# difference of data based on the subsequent date in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have some set of records(rows).
I want the subsequent difference of records based on selected date.
like, for 18/07/2013 the final result should contain `(record for 19/07/2013) - (record for 17/07/2013)`
For Ex -

```
178     632    17/07/2013  
192     785    18/07/2013
265     1012   21/07/2013
```

Then the result should come like this -

```
178-0      632-0      17/07/2013
192-178    785-632    18/07/2013
265-0      1012-0     21/07/2013
```

which is equivalent to

```
178     632    17/07/2013  
14      153    18/07/2013
265     1012   21/07/2013
```

Comment: look up window functions and LEAD and LAG functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one of the approaches using [LAG](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions082.htm#i1327527) analytical function which allows you to get access to rows prior to the current row.

```
-- sample of data from the question
with t1(col1, col2, col3) as(
  select 178, 632,    to_date('17/07/2013', 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all  
  select 192, 785,    to_date('18/07/2013', 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
  select 265, 1012,   to_date('21/07/2013', 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual
) -- the query
select to_char(col1) -
       decode( col3 - lag(col3, 1, col3) over(order by col3)
             , 1
             , lag(col1, 1, 0) over(order by col3)
             , 0
             )  as col1
     , to_char(col2) -
       decode( col3 - lag(col3, 1, col3) over(order by col3)
             , 1
             , lag(col2, 1, 0) over(order by col3)
             , 0
             ) as col2
     , col3
 from t1
```

Result:

```
COL1      COL2          COL3
--------------------------------------------------------
178       632       July, 17 2013 00:00:00+0000
14        153       July, 18 2013 00:00:00+0000
265       1012      July, 21 2013 00:00:00+0000
```

[**SQLFiddle DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/14237)

As another approach, you can use [model clause](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14223/sqlmodel.htm) to get the same result.

```
with t1(col1, col2, col3) as(
  select 178, 632,    to_date('17/07/2013', 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all  
  select 192, 785,    to_date('18/07/2013', 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
  select 265, 1012,   to_date('21/07/2013', 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual
)
select c1
     , c2
     , col3
  from t1
model 
dimension by(row_number() over(order by col3) as rn)
measures( cast(null as number) as c1
        , cast(null as number) as c2
        , col1
        , col2
        , col3)
rules(
  c1[rn] = decode( col3[cv()] - col3[cv() - 1]
                 , 1
                 , col1[cv()] - col1[cv() - 1]
                 , col1[cv()]
                 ), 
  c2[rn] = decode( col3[cv()] - col3[cv() - 1]
                 , 1
                 , col2[cv()] - col2[cv() - 1]
                 , col2[cv()]
                 )
)
```

Result:

```
C1      C2      COL3
----------------------------------------------
178     632     July, 17 2013 00:00:00+0000
14      153     July, 18 2013 00:00:00+0000
265     1012    July, 21 2013 00:00:00+0000
```

[**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/14245)

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov for the benefit of everyone can you please explain your answer

Comment: @NICHOLAS: that works awesomely... thanks a lot
but can u please elaborate, how u come up with such answer.....

Comment: @abhi You already had the logic to implement, the question was about means that will allow you to access previous and possibly next rows of a table. So as it has been already mentioned, functions `LAG` and `LEAD` will allow that. Read up on those functions [here(LAG)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions082.htm#i1327527), [here(LEAD)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions086.htm#SQLRF00656)(hasn't been used in the answer but is worth to be mentioned) and the [model clause](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14223/sqlmodel.htm)